# Почему о младенцах говорят: "выкладывать на животик"?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов, глаголы, приставка

Появился ребёнок, и выяснилось, что детей на живот *не кладут*, а ***выкладывают*.** Никак не могу к этому привыкнуть и не понимаю, ***зачем*** так говорить.
Что даёт приставка *вы-* в данном случае? По-моему, ***выложить*** я могу:

- огурчик на прилавок;
- фоточку в инстаграммчик;
- телефон из сумки;
- пол плиткой.

А вот с ребёнком (на живот) слово *выкладывать* у меня никак не идёт. Может, подчёркивается то, что ребёнок на животе беспомощно "корячится", и его надо быстро переворачивать обратно? Но он может вполне себе спать на животе, и тогда получается: когда он спит — я его *кладу* на живот, а когда не спит — *выкладываю*?

Было бы интересно узнать ваше мнение.

Answer (score 2):

Слово это не сегодня появилось и, возможно, при нынешнем уходе за грудничками и не было бы его. До недавнего времени всех детей пеленали, и их распелёнование было процессом извлечения из сложной упаковки. Это — не телефон из сумки выложить.

Слово *выкладывать* как процесс здесь самое подходящее. Кроме того, вылёживание (из той же колоды) на животе — необходимое положение, точнее — полезная смена положения тела, прежде долгое время находившееся на спине и неподвижно в плотном конверте.

Answer (score 2):

Выложить — **многозначное слово**, и употреблено оно не случайно. Поэтому надо выбрать из словаря подходящее значение.

Здесь возможны **варианты**: 1) Вынуть из пеленок, **освободить от одежды**. 2) Положить **в определённую позу**, которую совсем маленький ребенок ещё **не может изменить.**

Возможно, оба эти значение присутствуют в этом выражении.

**Из словаря:**

**ВЫЛОЖИТЬ**,  св. что. 1. во что, на что, куда. Положить куда-л., **вынув** откуда-л. В. покупки на прилавок. В. варенье из банки в вазочку. В. из шкафа бельё. 2. чем. Покрыть, какую-л. поверхность, уложив на ней что-л.; выстлать, вымостить. В. стены кафелем. В. дорожку галькой. 3. Сложить, соорудить (из камня, кирпича и т.п.). В. поленницу. В. печь. В. из мозаики орнамент.

Значение 3 может соответствовать значению "придать предмету определенное положение".